# called function refuses to return true

Tags: javascript

Even when sum === largest in subset(), I don't get a "true" in my console. The true is sent back only to the calling function? Then how do I get the "return true" to behave as a newbie would expect?

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr)
{
    arr.sort();
    var largest = arr.pop()
    subset([], arr, largest);
}


function subset(soFar, rest, largest)
{
    var sum = 0;
    if (rest.length === 0)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<soFar.length; i++)
        {
            sum+= soFar[i];            
        }
        if (sum === largest)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        var soFar2 = soFar.slice(0);
        soFar2.push(rest[0]);
        subset(soFar,rest.slice(1),largest);
        subset(soFar2, rest.slice(1),largest);
    }
}


ArrayAdditionI([85,3,88,2])
```

Comment: So… you want to `return subset([], arr, largest);`? JavaScript doesn’t have implicit returns.

Comment: I want to return a boolean to the console. I know I can console.log("true"), but it is curious that I can't return a boolean true like all my previous exercises have done.

Comment: Like I said, JavaScript doesn’t have implicit returns. The `ArrayAdditionI` function never attempts to return anything.

Comment: I arranged the return: `return subset([], arr, largest);` and var teste is undefined: `var test = ArrayAdditionI([85, 3, 88, 2]); console.log(test);`

Comment: @dwilbank I put a console.log('here'); inside subset funcion before var sum, and 'here' is showing just one time on my console.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr)
{
    arr.sort();
    var largest = arr.pop()
    var ret = subset([], arr, largest);
    // do something with ret
}


function subset(soFar, rest, largest)
{
    var sum = 0;
    if (rest.length === 0)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<soFar.length; i++)
        {
            sum+= soFar[i];            
        }
        if (sum === largest)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        var soFar2 = soFar.slice(0);
        soFar2.push(rest[0]);
        subset(soFar,rest.slice(1),largest);
        subset(soFar2, rest.slice(1),largest);
    }
    return false;
}


ArrayAdditionI([85,3,88,2])
```

Comment: Trying all these changes. Thanks. Still no luck though.

Comment: try returning ret and then logging ArrayAdditionI